# Combining Multiple API Request Simultaneously using Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm currently developing my android app and have a problem in displaying data retrieved from API in my Home Activity. Here is design for my Home activity.

[image]

On that page, I want to show three data: Latest news, most popular news, and categories. Each of the data obtained from different API. So, there are three API request when displaying the data.

The scenario that I want is to perform all requests simultaneously, showing a progress bar when taking such data and dismiss the progress bar when all of the data from such three API is successfully obtained. If I've got the latest news data, the progress bar wouldn't be dismissed until popular news and categories data successfully obtained. And when the latest news data and categories data successfully obtained, but I've got a problem when getting popular news, then all the data wouldn't be displayed on the page, and the page will display an error message.

I'm using retrofit in accessing my API. I've also tried combining it with RxJava for accessing the API. I've tried to use RxJava combine sequences method like combineLatest, merge, but the problem that I found is that it can't combine more than two requests/sequence at the same time. So I haven't met the solution.

Is there any good solution for this case?

Comment: Have you used `Observable.combineLatest()` family of methods? There's a lot of overloaded `combineLatest()` methods for any number of arguments you need (the same for `Observable.merge()`.

Comment: You right! I missed that combineLatest can combine more than two sequence. Now i solve that with using combineLatest like this:

`Observable.combineLatest(api.getLatest(), api.getPopular(),      api.getCategories(), (latest, popular,categories) -> {

      List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
      results.add(s1);
      results.add(s2);
      results.add(s3);
      return results;
   }).subscribe(results->{
       String latestData = results.get(0);   
       String popularData = results.get(1);   
       String categoriesData = results.get(2); 
    }
   )`

Thank

Comment: Hi may I know which schedulers did you use to achieve simultaneous network requests?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same case here, have you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My initial (incorrect) answer is struck through below. Apologies for the inaccuracy.

`combineLatest` does appear to do what you'd like. A current comment under the question has the right idea, but I think the handling of the emission of `combineLatest` can be done slightly better, so here is my take for that.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
            api.getLatest(),
            api.getPopular(),
            api.getCategories(),
            NewsReaderViewModel::new)
            // This is very simple progress bar logic, and will actually break if this code
            // errors. Handling of the progress bar should be slightly different, but for the
            // sake of this example, I'm going to keep it as simple as possible.
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))
            // Depending on your requirements, you might not need to continue observing this
            // stream. If you expect your results are going to continue to be updated, then
            // you won't want to add this next line, but I don't imagine this data is going to
            // live update.
            .firstElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::displayResults, out::println);
```

I created the NewsReaderViewModel to hold the results, as you may want to perform some logic on the results, and couldn't do that in a reasonable way when using the ArrayList solution. Here is the NewsReaderViewModel class. It is very simple and just contains three lists of Strings.

```
static final class NewsReaderViewModel {

    final List<String> latest;
    final List<String> popular;
    final List<String> categories;

    NewsReaderViewModel(List<String> latest, List<String> popular, List<String> categories) {
        this.latest = latest;
        this.popular = popular;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

I've omitted the rest of the code, but here is a link to the Github repository with the full example that you'll be able to clone and run. Let me know if you have any questions and I hope this helps!

[Here is the Github link](https://github.com/lustigdev/StackOverflowProblems/blob/stackoverflow/combine-multiple-api-calls/app/src/main/java/com/example/michaellustig/dynamicnetworkrequests/MainActivity.java)
I'll also upload a YouTube video of the thought process behind the answer and link that video once it's available. Sometimes it's even more seeing the thoughts and mistakes and process behind the answer rather than just the answer itself.

<s>I think you may actually want to use zip rather than combine latest. Zip will wait until all of the zipped observables have emitted once. That sounds closer to your requirements.</s>

Here is the documentation for zip: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

You'll subscribe to the resultant stream of zip and will display the results of the UI there and hide the progress bar. If you use combineLatest, you'll have to check in the resultant subscription whether or not the contents are null, and that is not idiomatic Rx

Comment: I think `combineLatest` also won't emit until all of the combined observables have emitted at least one value.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My apologies for the incorrect answer. Do you know what the right thing to do here is? Should I delete the answer or edit it? I think I'm going to edit it with code from ikhsan's answer but slightly modified. I don't think passing the resultant values in faux tuple is a great solution.